# Create a row according to empty DataTable Definition

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, ado.net

After executing DataAdapter and get an empty DataTable. I need to create a new row according to empty datatable definition. Please help in this point.

```
    SqlConnection con = CreateCon(); 
     SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(); 
     da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand();
     da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
     da.SelectCommand.Connection = con;  da.SelectCommand.CommandText = "spGET_RackZone"; 

     if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
     {
     con.Open(); 
    }
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     da.Fill(ds);
     if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open){ 
     con.Close(); 
    }

 DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
```

Now I want to create a row when datatable is empty.

Comment: You can create it by using a DataRow object

Comment: I can use this DataRow newBlankRow1 = dataTable.NewRow(). But I need to create datarow according to table definition.

Comment: check if its empty then add new row  `if(dt.Rows.Count==0){ 
DataRow newRow = dataTable.NewRow(); //Add your values }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
         DataTable table = new DataTable();
         if(table.Rows.Count==0)
            {
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            table.Rows.Add(row);
            }
         //if you already know the column of the table    
         table.Columns.Add("sl.No", typeof(int));
         table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

        // Here we add a DataRow.
        table.Rows.Add(57, "Amin");
```